# Resume code after catching exception

Tags: java, oracle, jnlp

I am trying to return false if my code catches an exception but it seems like to stop when it catches an exception.

Here's my code:

First method

```
while ((reachable == false) && (cnt <= 2)) {
            serverName = FPRODDB[cnt][0];
            sid = FPRODDB[cnt][1];
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            reachable = TestDB(conn);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Testing Connection: " + String.valueOf(cnt) ); 
            cnt ++;
        }
```

Second method: The TestDb Method, the one put in reachable variable.

```
public boolean TestDB(Connection conn) throws Exception{

try {
    if (conn ==null || conn.isClosed()) {
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
} catch (Exception e){
       return false;
}

}
```

EDIT: Here's my Error

```
java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at digicare.tracking.serial.BulkUpload.DatabaseConnection.OracleConnection.GetDB(OracleConnection.java:45)
    at digicare.tracking.serial.BulkUpload.DatabaseConnection.OracleConnection.main(OracleConnection.java:13)
    at digicare.tracking.serial.BulkUpload.UploadProgress$1read2.run(UploadProgress.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:328)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:421)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:630)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:127)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:126)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:306)
```

Comment: What is the value of cnt. If thats greater than 2 its going to break out the loop anyway

Comment: where do you call the first method from the second method?

Comment: cnt will be at 0 on the first execution....

Comment: @Evgeny 2nd method was the one called on the first method...

Comment: Perhaps you are running out of connections as you are not closing them. Once this happens, every attempt to get a new one will fail.

Comment: No Sir @PeterLawrey I put the wrong server names so it would return false and continue with the other database name, So definitely no connections where made. And whenever I try to put the correct database name it works fine..

Comment: It is not clear what you are saying, but after it fails once it should try again. If it fails twice, the whole things fails.  If it appears to be doing something else then you need to investigate further, i.e. the answer is not in the code.

Comment: I am trying to test the connection of my application to my databases(it will only connect to 1 database at a time, but if the first db is unreachable it will find the next available db). Inside the while loop, if the TestDB method catches an exception bacause of the conn == null or the conn.isclosed I want it to return false so it will enter the while loop again. but my problem is after TestDB catches an exception it didn't return false. instead it just stops. Thanks in advance

Comment: @PeterLawrey Do I need to close the connections even after declaring it conn.getdriver etc..? or I just need to close it in conn == null and conn.isclosed()?

Comment: only `conn.close()` will close the connection.  Setting it to `null` discards it and `conn.isClosed()` tests whether you closed it already.  `Connection timed out: connect` would indicate to me the Oracle was not accepting more connections because its limit has been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding a try block on the

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

on the first method.
it looks like this:

```
try {
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  reachable = TestDB(conn);
} catch (Exception e) {
   reachable = false;
}
```

It is because the error is not with the second method. the error is the declaration of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Could it just be that it's DriverManager.getConnection that throws the exception. Because as the code is written now, you only catch the exception thrown by conn.isClosed().

Answer (score 1):

because before your try catch block ,there is a Exception happening, and ,the try catch block can catch no Expcetion at all,may be u want to catch the code inner while loop, as the method getConnection alwayse throw an Exception if u give the wrong url、port、username or password

Comment: You're right the error is with the getConnection in the first method. but even surrounding it with try/catch it still doesn't continue with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  peter Lawrey.and did you try to run in debug mode and checked what exaclty happening in TestDB method?

Can you also use stacktrace in your catch block and share the full stack trace here.

BTW are you handeling exception in first method, the method to which while loop belong?

Comment: I put in the printstacktrace before and it says connection timed out. Because I put the wrong database name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct your if condition

```
if (conn ==null || conn.isClosed())
```

By this

```
if (conn !=null && conn.isClosed())
```

Your if statement may throw error if it is null at `conn.isClosed()`

However you have catch exception and try with `return;` instead of `return false;` and you can put your stackTrace so exact error may identify.

Comment: will the return end the method or just the try block?

Comment: It will return from method without throwing exception and by seeing your stack trace `DriverManager.getConnection` is throwing exception there is not issue with `TestDB()` method it is fine.

Comment: yeah the error is with the first method. when I declare the connection. the getconnection is causing an error. how can I prevent it from stoping even after catching an exception? Please Up vote my question hahaha thanks

Comment: Put it in separate method and enclosed it with try..catch block like second method. Normal practice is to write all database connecting code in separate method, so try to reconstruct your code in efficient manner

Comment: Then just enclosed it with try..catch

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing **Throws Exception** ?

change

```
public boolean TestDB(Connection conn) throws Exception{
```

to

```
public boolean TestDB(Connection conn){
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this statement, instead of the many lines you wrote.

```
try{
    return !conn.isClosed(); //true if open
}catch(Exception e){
    return false; //is false if nullPointerException is thrown (that mean conn is null)
}
```

This will simplify the code.
At the end I think you should use a big try-catch that contains all the code, so everything is exception checked

```
while ((reachable == false) && (cnt <= 2)) {
        serverName = FPRODDB[cnt][0];
        sid = FPRODDB[cnt][1];
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        reachable = TestDB(conn);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "Testing Connection: " + String.valueOf(cnt) ); 
        cnt ++;
    }catch(Exception e){
        // tell the user, or handle it
    }
    }
```